# How do I set folder ACL's with Web deploy in VS2010?

Tags: asp.net, acl, webdeploy

I have a web application I want to deploy via Web Deploy, using "Build Deployment Package"

It has a folder called "Errors". This is part of the project. Web Deploy adds it, but how do I specify that i want the application to have Write permissions on this folder?

Do I have to manually edit the source manifest each time, or can I set it somewhere to get the package to do it automagically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure if this will help, but there is a command called [Set-Acl](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315261.aspx). This can then be used to [Set-Acl provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569047%28WS.10%29.aspx). As a side note, [this blog post](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2010/09/24/debugging-delegation-rules-for-web-deploy.aspx) seems to be dealing with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx#7611626) on Web Deployment. The post in itself is not on your topic, but there's a comment in there (search for '.csproj'; comment should be yellow) that shows how to disable Web Deploy to make set-acl-s in your manifest. Maybe you can go from there.

Comment: as a note to that, there is a blog which deals with that comment here http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/rick/prevent-visual-studio-2010-and-web-deploy-from-changing-acls/